# Google auto complete given wrong latitude and longitude

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have using Google Map API for auto complete to my project. Sometimes the address given wrong latitude and longitude.

> 21 King Street West, Toronto, ON, Canada

First time I get :

```
40.7917804,-74.14482129999999 - wrong (USA Address)
```

Second time I get :

```
43.64877740000001,-79.37871480000001
```

Here is my code :

```
var address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(id)‌​), {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'ca'
    }
});
address.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = address.getPlace();
    $j('#' + txtboxid).attr({
        'data-lat': place.geometry.location.lat(),
        'data-lon': place.geometry.location.lng()
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: I believe it uses your IP address to determine your location when you are using a computer (phones have GPS, *most* computers don't). Thus, it is always bound to be a little out.

Comment: `code`
var address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(id)),
{ types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: { country: 'ca' } });
            address.addListener('place_changed', function () {
               var place = address .getPlace();
$j('#' + txtboxid).attr({
                            'data-lat': place.geometry.location.lat(),
                            'data-lon': place.geometry.location.lng()
                        });
            });

Comment: Its because when they click on address in dropdown the api called before the complete text filled in the address field. print the api call parameters in console and have a look at it you will understand what i mean.

Comment: Even you may test on enter key press it will be working fine by the way the blur function or whatever function you use where you got that value of input or where the api drop down activated, get that value after 0.1 msec by using setTimeout(function () {},0.1);